# Creating images of notes in music21

Tags: python, music21

I get an error when running:

```
from music21 import *

n1 = note.Note('C4', quarterLength=1)
n2 = note.Note('A4', quarterLength=1)
s = stream.Stream()
s.append(n1)
s.append(n2)
s.show('lily.svg')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.show('lily.svg')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\base.py", line 2206, in show
    return formatWriter.show(self, regularizedConverterFormat, app=app, subformats=subformats, **keywords)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 277, in show
    returnedFilePath = self.write(obj, fmt, subformats=subformats, **keywords)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 245, in write
    conv = lily.translate.LilypondConverter()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\lily\translate.py", line 147, in __init__
    self.setupTools()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\lily\translate.py", line 177, in setupTools
    versionString = versionString.split()[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have installed scipy and mathplotlib so music21 doesn't complain anymore about them not being available.
I run Python 3.4 on Windows 7.

If I instead use `s.show('musicxml.png')` to get my images I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.show('musicxml.png')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\base.py", line 2206, in show
    return formatWriter.show(self, regularizedConverterFormat, app=app, subformats=subformats, **keywords)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 147, in show
    returnedFilePath = self.write(obj, fmt, subformats=subformats, **keywords)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 637, in write
    fp = self.runThroughMusescore(fp, **keywords)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\converter\subConverters.py", line 606, in runThroughMusescore
    elif not os.path.exists(musescoreFile):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: can't specify None for path argument
```

What do I have to do to get images (preferably svg)?

Comment: Do you have [lilypond](http://www.lilypond.org) or [musescore](http://musescore.org/) installed in your system? I've checked the source code and it is trying to locate those applications. Lilypond for the svg output and musescore for the png.

Comment: I have lilypond installed at in my path as `C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin`

Comment: If you edit this file: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\music21\lily\translate.py and insert '_print versionString_' on line 177, before '_versionString = versionString.split()[-1]
_' you might see the error you are getting.

Answer (score 7):

**LILYPOND**

I had same error. I have managed to configure LilyPond for music21 in the following way:

1. Moved LilyPond folder to path without blank spaces (from `C:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin` to `C:\LilyPond\usr\bin`). 
   I saw in music21 code that it does not put necessary quotas around path when executing lilypond command, so had to resolve the problem this way.
2. [Created configuration file in music21 and set lilypondPath](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/tutorials/environment.html)

   ```
   us = environment.UserSettings()
   us.create()
   us['lilypondPath'] = 'C:/LilyPond/usr/bin/lilypond.exe'
   ```

   you can check whether it is set properly:

   ```
   print us['lilypondPath']
   ```
3. Well, this might be not necessary, but during my attempts I restarted everything several times, so you may try it at the end if everything does not work immediately.

**MUSESCORE**

1. Just in case, installed [Musescore](https://musescore.org/en/download) to path without blank spaces (
2. Added twice musescore path to environment (found this new way of setting environment variables), once as `"musescoreDirectPNGPath"`:

   `environment.set("musescoreDirectPNGPath",     "C:/MuseScore2/bin/MuseScore.exe")`

   and then as `"musicxmlPath"`:

   `environment.set("musicxmlPath", "C:/MuseScore2/bin/MuseScore.exe")`
3. After several tries, debugging etc. I have learnt that it is important to pass in file name '.xml' extension instead of '.png' if we want to use Musescore:

   stream_name.show('musicalxml.xml')

   Musescore cannot open .png file, but it can open .xml file.

Finally, I can add some code that generates files without opening lilypond or musescore. Hope that someone finds it usefull

LILYPOND:

```
# music21object - stream or score or any object that can be showed
conv =  music21.converter.subConverters.ConverterLilypond()
scorename = 'myScoreName'
filepath = 'C:/path/to/musical_scores/' + scorename
conv.write(music21object, fmt = 'lilypond', fp=filepath, subformats = ['pdf'])
```

MUSESCORE:

```
from music21.converter.subConverters import ConverterMusicXML
conv_musicxml = ConverterMusicXML()
scorename = 'myScoreName.xml'
filepath = 'C:/path/to/musical_scores/' + scorename
out_filepath = conv_musicxml.write(music21object, 'musicxml', fp=filepath, subformats=['png'])
```

Notice, that scorename has '.xml' extension.

Unfortunately, it does not save file in the specified filepath. Musescore adds "-1" to filename, but it is possible to get this changed filepath (as out_filepath in code above) and rename later to what we want.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to setup musescore with a path with spaces. The most Important thing is to make sure to use inverted slash. This is how I did it:

```
# Create the user environment for music21
us = m21.environment.UserSettings()
us['musicxmlPath'] = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MuseScore 2/bin/MuseScore.exe'
us['musescoreDirectPNGPath'] = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MuseScore 2/bin/MuseScore.exe'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

try
#sudo apt-get update to install lilypond
!apt-get update
!apt-get -y install lilypond

else the additional files that the lilypond wishes to download fails due to an outdated system.