# How to display musical notation using music21 in ipython/python with MuseScore WITHOUT MuseScore re-opening every time .show() is called?

Tags: python, ipython, music21

I am using music21 with MuseScore in an ipython notebook. It works well, the only problem is that every time I create a Stream and then run my_stream.show(), it takes a forever because it waits to open the MuseScore application. This happens even if MuseScore is already open (it opens a second copy of the app, which then closes itself after the image is printed).

How can I prevent music21 from re-opening MuseScore each time and get it to use the already opened app instead?

EDIT: Adding version/OS info

I'm on a mac (OSX 10.10.4) using MuseScore version 2.1.0

I've also tried the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879764/creating-images-of-notes-in-music21) to print out sheet music in an ipython notebook but the same thing happened.

For the second method at least, the problem seems to be in [music21/converter/subConverter.py](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/blob/master/music21/converter/subConverters.py).

Under

```
class ConverterMusicXML(SubConverter):
```

There's this section:

```
    musescoreRun = '"' + musescorePath + '" ' + fp + " -o " + fpOut + " -T 0 "
    if 'dpi' in keywords:
        musescoreRun += " -r " + str(keywords['dpi'])

    if common.runningUnderIPython():
        musescoreRun += " -r " + str(defaults.ipythonImageDpi)

    storedStrErr = sys.stderr
    fileLikeOpen = six.StringIO()
    sys.stderr = fileLikeOpen
    os.system(musescoreRun)
    fileLikeOpen.close()
    sys.stderr = storedStrErr
```

I believe that this line in particular

```
os.system(musescoreRun)
```

is opening MuseScore independently each time, but I can't figure out what to replace it with that will allow music21 to find the already running instance of MuseScore.

Comment: It may have something to do with your OS.  On Mac it works fine and last time I checked, on PC worked great too.  More info about OS etc. would need to be there

Comment: Ok I added a lot more info about the versions/OS and where I suspect the problem is.

And thanks for music21 by the way Michael! It's been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem errors. Here refers an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/issues/348#issuecomment-506508228):

> ... changing `os.system(musescoreRun)` line 891 of subconverters.py by `subprocess.run(musescoreRun)`. You need also to import subprocess at the start of subconverters.py.

Maybe it works for you!